# Is there any software VGA dummy solution?

Tags: gpu

To cut long story short, I actually run  [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)  on a Intel HD 4600 based server on [Hetzner auction](http://serverbidding.com). And they all don't come with any remote KVM, or use any VGA dummy plug, for every server under auction. 

Now, how do I 'lie' to the server so the iGPU turns on? Sometimes, forcing opening Resolve from TeamViewer works (because TeamViewer actually mirrors the GPU output), but Teamviewer itself is buggy with headless server, and sometimes it returns black screen.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton DaVinci Resolve could not find any GPU (when there's HD 4600, which is unoficially supported). That happens only on RDP though, on TeamViewer it works fine, but TeamViewer itself was buggy with headless machine (random black screen)